# Lockmode PESSIMISTIC_WRITE in criteria vs select for update

Tags: mysql, hibernate, innodb, hibernate-criteria, readwritelock

Is there any significant difference in performance in using PESSIMISTIC_WRITE as LockMode in hibernate criteria as an alternative for Select for update query.

Use case involves following points:

1. Restrictions on values in multiple columns like status, time
2. Sorting on multiple columns
3. Select only the first row for processing.

This processing is done simultaneously by multiple machines/threads.
I am currently using hibernate criteria, and that is causing timeouts in getting lock multiple times, which results in choking of all other queries.

Comment: Are you sure that Hibernate actually implements `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` for MySQL/MariaDB?

Comment: Yes, there is for MySQL. ALthough I am using InnoDB engine instead of MariaDB

Comment: What SQL is generated for `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`?  What little I could find says `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` (in InnoDB).  When traffic is low and queries are fast, you are unlikely to hit the question.

Comment: there can be 5 concurrent requests.

Comment: yes it SELECT for UPDATE in InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the `FOR UPDATE` is "required" for proper concurrency:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT x ... FROM t ... FOR UPDATE;
use `x` for whatever
UPDATE t ...;
COMMIT;
```

Without `FOR UPDATE`, the value of `x` could change, thereby potentially invalidating the intent of the `UPDATE`.